# Using OCMockito how can one verify any selector was passed to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, ocmockito

I have a view controller that adds itself as an observer of UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification during viewDidLoad.  I'd like to verify that this happens but I don't want the test to care what specific selector the view controller registers for the event.

Currently my test looks something like this:

```
- (void)testRegistersForApplicationDidBecomeActiveEvent
{
   //given
   MyViewController *sut = [MyViewController new];
   NSNotificationCenter* mockNotificationCenter = mock([NSNotificationCenter class);

   //when
   [sut view];

   //then
   [verify([mockNotificationCenter]) addObserver:sut
                                        selector:anything()
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
}
```

...but passing "anything()" for the selector gives a compiler error: "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC".

I can make the test work if I pass "@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)" instead of anything.  That is the exact selector the view controller uses.  But I'd prefer the test not have that much knowledge of the specific implementation, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`anything()` is applicable only for `id` ([from the `OCHamcrest` API](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest/blob/master/Source/Core/HCMatcher.h)) which states for an object and `selector` states for a method.

I would raise issue on the GitHub and right now provide extra knowledge in test with specifying exact.

I think it should be quite easy contribution (since providing exact selector is working for test)